# Calculate full smith normal form

Tags: linear-algebra

M = \begin{bmatrix}
3 &  5  & 6 & 7\\
\end{bmatrix}

I want to calculate USV = M.

So that S is Smith normal form.

So now i use the allowed Gauß Operations to :

M = \begin{bmatrix}
3 &  5  & 0 & 7\\
\end{bmatrix}

But i can't remove the 5 and 7 because it is not divisible by a multiple of 3 and only integer multiple are allowed to compute the smith normal form.

Answer (score 2):

You basically need to do the steps as in the Euclidean Algorithm:

Subtract 3 from 5, get 2. (More generally, you write 5=x*3+r, subtract x times the 3 and get remainder 3.

Then subtract 2 from 3 and get 1.

The rest is should be easy.